# How to send data from html to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am using the following `form` to send data to my mongodb server.

```
  <form action="/tasks" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="test">
    <button>Add Data</button>
  </form>
```

This form connects to my `POST` request via the following

```
const express = require('express');
const taskController = require("./controllers/TaskController");
require("./config/db");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app
  .route("/tasks")
  .get(taskController.listAllTasks)
  .post(taskController.createNewTask);

...

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening at port ${port}`);
});
```

The `POST` requests are handled by `createNewTask` function in my controller

```
const Task = require("../models/Task");
...
// Create a new task and save it to database
exports.createNewTask = (req, res) => {
  let test = res.json(req.body.test)
  let newTask = new Task(test);
  console.log(newTask)
  newTask.save((err, task) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    res.status(201).json(task);
  });
};
```

The controller gets the following Schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const TaskSchema = new Schema({
  taskName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  createdOn: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Tasks", TaskSchema);
```

After watching a tutorial, my intuition was that `form action="/tasks"` in `index.html` correlates to `app.route("tasks")` in `index.js`.

My `input name="test"` also seems to correlate to `res.json(req.body.test)`.

I chose `res.json` because I figured I would have to send `JSON` data from the input instead of a string to the server.

However, after I submit `{"taskName": "lol"}` into my input from `http://localhost:3000/`, I get sent to `http://localhost:3000/tasks` with the following result

```
"{\"taskName\": \"lol\"}"
```

with an error

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

How do I properly send my html data to the server?

My [github](https://github.com/develijahlee/quotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was

```
let test = res.json(req.body.test)
```

This sends one response to the server and

```
res.status(201).json(task);
```

Sends a second response. The error thus comes from sending two responses when I am only allowed one.

Rewriting the code to

```
exports.createNewTask = (req, res) => {
  let newTask = new Task(JSON.parse(req.body.test));
  newTask.save((err, task) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      res.status(201).json(task);
    }
  });
};
```

Solves the problem by passing a `JSON` sting into the input and converting it into a Javascript object

Answer (score 2):

You should do here an **if / else**

```
 newTask.save((err, task) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    res.status(201).json(task);
  });
```

**To this**

```
 newTask.save((err, task) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    }else{
    res.status(201).json(task);
    }
  });
```

In case of an error your code will first send the **error 500** and then will send `res.status(201).json(task);`

Comment: I tried that and the error remains the same.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error but I stuck at another error. 
I cloned your repository and receive this error `MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.`

Comment: That's because I'm using `process.env.MONGO_URI` for the first parameter of `mongoose.connect` because I didn't want to leak my dbname and dbpassword in the open and decided to store them in a `.env` file that is not tracked by git via `gitignore`

Comment: oh lol sure, I ve an own atlas account then I will try it with this